# Why do I see ClassCastException in Groovy through @Delegate method

Tags: spring, groovy, amazon-swf

I have a class (I'm using the library [Glisten](https://github.com/Netflix/glisten)) that defines a @Delegate member.

```
class PendingActionWorkflowImpl implements PendingActionWorkflow, WorkflowOperator<PendingActionWorkflow> {

    /***
     * The @Delegate transformation makes all the methods from WorkflowOperations
     * available to owning class (PendingActionWorkflowImpl)
     */
    @Delegate
    WorkflowOperations<PendingActionActivities> workflowOperations =
            SwfWorkflowOperations.of(PendingActionActivities)

}
```

When I access a nested member of WorkflowOperations ('activities') i get a ClassCastException however if I access the WorkflowOperations property first, then everything works okay...

```
 Promise<List<String>> promise = promiseFor(activities.fetchPendingActions())
```

Scratching my head on this one.

Here is the exception for completeness:

> Details = org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
>   cast object 'com.netflix.glisten.impl.swf.AsyncCaller(interface
>   com..wf.pending.PendingActionActivities, null,
>   com.netflix.glisten.impl.swf.AsyncCaller$DynamicActivitiesClientFactory(class
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.DynamicActivitiesClientImpl))'
>   with class 'com.netflix.glisten.impl.swf.AsyncCaller' to class
>   'com..wf.pending.PendingActionActivities'     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603)

Comment: Do you have a runnable example that reproduces the problem?